# Kubeflow on kubernetes, ksonnet apply function is not reacting properly?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, ksonnet, kubeflow

I'm trying the following codelab:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kubeflow-introduction/index.html

When I want to apply my container to the cluster the shell freezes and after a couple of minutes it returns 'Killed'.
[image]

This is the current file structure:
[image]

Comment: Check logs at /var/log/kern.log. This may be occurring due to the cloud shell being too small & running out of memory. See [0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136291/will-linux-start-killing-my-processes-without-asking-me-if-memory-gets-short) for more details about the "killed" message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cloudshell is indeed probably too small to run this so you need to run the cloudshell in boosted mode[image: How to enable boost mode]